# Login to Github via PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, github, oauth-2.0, github-api

I'm making a website where people can connect their Github account.

I had registered my application into developers applications on Github to have Client ID and Client Secret Key.

Now, I want to redirect people to Github's login page with a cURL in PHP. 
The only thing I found in the documentation is this command line with curl but I don't know how to use it in PHP.

```
curl -u username https://api.github.com/user
```

Thanks to help !

-----------Edit-------------

Well, I used this tutorial about Oauth on Github : http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-add-github-oauth-login-on-your-website-using-php_740.html

Everything works fine until the authorization. 
Then I get this error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\codesourcing\github\index.php on line 19
Some error occured try again
```

Line 19  is the if($gitResponce->access_token) below:

```
    $data = array('url' => 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
                  'data' => $postvars,
                  'header' => array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept: application/json"),
                  'method' => 'POST');

    $gitResponce = json_decode(curlRequest($data));

    if($gitResponce->access_token)
    {
        $data = array('url' => 'https://api.github.com/user?access_token='.$gitResponce->access_token,
                      'header' => array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","User-Agent: ".appName,"Accept: application/json"),
                      'method' => 'GET');

        $gitUser = json_decode(curlRequest($data));
echo '
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><a href="'.$gitUser->html_url.'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$gitUser->avatar_url.'" width="200px" height="200px"/></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td>'.$gitUser->name.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td>'.$gitUser->email.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Location:</td>
                <td>'.$gitUser->location.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Website:</td>
                <td>'.$gitUser->blog.'</td>
            </tr>
        </table>';
```

Comment: If you want a user to log into their GitHub account, you probably want to use [GitHub's OAuth](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/). You may find it easier to use a library [like this](https://github.com/KnpLabs/php-github-api) or [this one](https://github.com/joeworkman/github_oauth)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a curl php basic authentication

```
<?php
$username='username';
$password='password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.github.com/user');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($status_code);
print_r($result);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But your code use raw username/password data, I would like to redirect people to Github's login page like it is explained in the API in Ruby language. My goal is to register people on my website by their Github account like we can do with Facebook or Google+.

Comment: @Joss curl -u username https://api.github.com/user is for basic authentication only. Check https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication. You can check oauth, this will suffice your requiremnt. Please have a look at http://www.9lessons.info/2014/02/login-with-github-oauth-php.html